# Running feature file multiple times without passing a value from feature file

Tags: c#, selenium, cucumber

I have a feature file like this.

```
Feature: Verify captured document values against CMS for 
@test
Scenario: Verify user can open and view document
    Given user is in QueueHandling home page Dashboard
    And user has batches assigned to himself/herself
    When user selects a batch from batch list
    Then selected batch is opened in a new window
    And user views all identified documents

@test
Scenario Outline: Verify data in document
    When user selects "<documentType>" document and compare data

Examples:
| documentType         |
| Settlement Coversheet|
| AssetLoanAgreement   |

@test
Scenario: Verify user navigates back to QueueHandling home page Dashboard
    Given user navigates back to QueueHandling home page Dashboard
```

I want to run it multiple times within the code.

"When user selects a batch from batch list" in this step I want to pass batch number one by one each time this feature is running.

I tried to add a loop to BeforeFeature like this.

```
[BeforeFeature]
        [Obsolete]
        public static void BeforeFeature()
        {
            while (queueNumberCurrentIndex < 2)
            {
                string featureAddOnText = queueNumberList[queueNumberCurrentIndex];
                feature = extent.CreateTest(FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title + "  \"" + featureAddOnText + "\"", FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Description);
                Hooks.testlog = extentLog.CreateTest(Properties.getProperty("projectname"));
                feature.AssignCategory("Regression");               
            }
        }
```

But this keeps on running forever. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber is not an environment to program in.

If you need to program, you need to either push the programming down into your step definitions or better yet helper methods called by your step definitions, or pull the code up, so you do things like have scripts that dynamically create features.

Most of the time pushing the programming down is the simplest answer. If you implement a step definition as a single call, you end up in a pretty powerful programming environment in your programming language of choice. Here you can loop, collate, connect to external resources etc. etc.

In you example the programming is all focused on how something is being done. The first step to pushing this down is to understand WHAT your scenario is trying to do and WHY that is important. Currently your scenario fails to do this. It claims that WHAT it is about is that `a user can open and view a document`. If this was actually the case your scenario would be

```
Given the user has a document
When they open their document
Then they should see their document
```

But your scenario is all about batches verification settlement, loans. You won't make any progress without expressing  a much clearer description of WHAT the combined effects of all these interactions are for, and WHY this particular combination of interactions is important.